# Including multiple JQuery plug-ins Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've only just started using JQuery so be easy on me if the solution is something simple.

My problem is that I have 2 Jquery plug-ins on the same page, but only 1 of which works, depending on the order the files have been included.  See below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" href="/js/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
//no conflict jquery
jQuery.noConflict();
//jquery stuff
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/moocheck.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js_main.js"></script>
```

In the code posted above, the styling of the checkboxes works fine, but the datepicker doesn't.  If I remove the 2 mootools JS lines, then the datepicker works OK.

Any ideas please?

Comment: mootools is not a jquery plugin.

Comment: Library? Sorry for the possibly misleading thread-title, as a said, I'm new to using Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery instead of $ for the datepicker.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
});
```

Comment: That, in addition to the changes made from everyone else's help, has made it work :).  I'm a first time question asker, so is there anything else I should do to the posts that have helped, other than vote up?

Answer (score 4):

You have included two different versions of jQuery on the same page, remove one of them (the older one probably).

Also there might be a conflict between jQuery and MooTools, I would try using [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), also see ["Using jQuery and MooTools Together"](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools).

Comment: That was daft of me, didn't actually notice it but I still can't solve the issue.  I removed the <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> line but no joy.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I updated my question to include noConflict but I'm still having the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading 2 version of jquery, so delete

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>`

Also, jquery ui should be loaded at the top right after jquery.

Comment: Deleted that line and moved the UI line to just below the main Jquery file but no luck :(